# tracking down the html page causing "no applicable method for 'xml_find_all'" error

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing

I have a folder of 30,000 html pages that I'm parsing with this R function:

```
extract <- function(x){
  file <- read_html(x)
  filename <- x %>% gsub("~/files/index.html", "", .)
  mapscript_vector <- file %>% 
    html_nodes("#mapscript") %>% 
    html_text() %>%
    str_match_all("markers \\= \\[\n\n\t *\\[ ?\"(.+)\", \"(\\w+)\", ([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+), ([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+), \"(\\d+)\", (\\d+)")  %>% 
    extract2(1) %>% 
    extract(2:7)
  mapscript_full_vector <- c(mapscript_vector, filename)
}

result <- lapply(html_files, extract)
```

It works as expected on subsets of the 30,000 files. But I guess there's a bad file or two in there somewhere, because when I run the function on the whole set, I'm getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "xml_document"
```

I guess I could do one of at least three things:

- find the file(s) causing the problems
- improve the code so that it can *also* deal with objects of class "xml_document"
- get the code to ignore problem files and give me a result for the rest

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: The error is a bit misleading. Objects of class `xml_document` can be supplied to `xml2::xml_find_all`. The most likely issue is that some of your files are empty.

Comment: Is there no way to implement a counter in magrittr-ese?

Comment: Thanks @neilfws--there was indeed an empty file. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tryCatch` like this to identify the names of the files that cause errors, and what errors they caused:

```r
extract <- function(x){
  tryCatch(
  {file <- read_html(x)
  filename <- x %>% gsub("~/files/index.html", "", .)
  mapscript_vector <- file %>% 
    html_nodes("#mapscript") %>% 
    html_text() %>%
    str_match_all("markers \\= \\[\n\n\t *\\[ ?\"(.+)\", \"(\\w+)\", ([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+), ([[:digit:]\\.\\-]+), \"(\\d+)\", (\\d+)")  %>% 
    extract2(1) %>% 
    extract(2:7)
  mapscript_full_vector <- c(mapscript_vector, filename)},
  error = function(e) {
    print(e)
    print(x)
  })
}

result <- lapply(html_files[1:100], extract)
```

This approach will give you a sense of how frequently the errors occur, and if it is a problem with your general function of just with a few empty files. I would try with just 100 files to start with as coded, and increase if there are no errors.

Comment: I found the solution from a comment above (one of the files was empty) but am grateful to learn about `tryCatch`, which will help me next time there's a hard-to-find error. Thanks.